# JQuery doesn't work after adding ajax (Node.js, PUG)

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax, pug

I have been trying to add like functionality to my blog posts website.

When i click on the numbers of like link it should run ajax call.
In my server.js file i have a function that receives post request updates number of likes for the given post in mongodb database.
I have set name attribute of the link to equal post_id so that i can modified that post in databse.

```
html

head
    style
        include ../styles/home.css
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/css/materialize.min.css')
    script(src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/js/materialize.min.js')
    script(src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js')
    script.
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.number_of_likes').click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                alert('This part wont run');
                $.ajax(
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '/like',
                    data: {'post_id' : $(this).attr('name')},
                    success: function(result){
                        alert('it works');
                    },
                    dataType: 'json'
                );
            });
        });

h2 Welcome to the main page
br
br
br
br
br
mixin postCard(postData)
    .post_container
        .row
            .col.s12.m6
                .card.blue-grey.darken-1
                    .card-content.white-text
                        span.card-title #{postData.title}
                        p= postData.content
                    .card-action
                        a(href='#') #{postData.username}
                        a(href='/delete_post/'+postData._id) Delete
                        a(href='' name=postData_id class='number_of_likes') #{postData.likes} 

each post in result
    +postCard(post)
```

But click event doesn't get fired.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is probably because this is invalid syntax causing the entire application to come to a halt:

```
$.ajax(
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/like',
    data: {'post_id' : $(this).attr('name')},
    success: function(result){
        alert('it works');
    },
    dataType: 'json'
);
```

You need to pass it as an object with the data between `{` and `}` like this:

```
 $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/like',
    data: {'post_id' : $(this).attr('name')},
    success: function(result){
        alert('it works');
    },
    dataType: 'json'
});
```